# optimizing left join query or creating an equivalent mysql query

Tags: mysql, left-join

I create two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hash_id` char(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `hash_id` (`hash_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `table2_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `table2_id` (`table2_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `table1_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`table2_id`) REFERENCES `table2` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The goal is two select some rows from `table1` by their id and information from `table2` according to corresponding `table2_id`. The following query with LEFT JOIN gives me exactly what I want.

```
SELECT t1.id, p1.hash_id, p1.name
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT id,name,hash_id FROM table2)
 as p1
ON t1.table2_id = p1.id
WHERE t1.id IN ('1','3')
```

But it seems to be not very efficient. How it could be optimized? Or maybe you can advise some equivalent query? You can see result of explain here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5502f/13/0

Comment: if you look the time when he posted his answer , i posted the answer first , i think he copy paste my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need to left join on all those columns. Just do left join on column which are relevant. So do following

```
 SELECT t1.id, t2.hash_id, t2.name , t2.id
 FROM table1 as t1
 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
 ON t1.table2_id = t2.id
 WHERE t1.id IN ('1','3')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     SELECT t1.id, t2.hash_id, t2.name , t2.id as id2
     FROM table1 as t1
     LEFT JOIN table2 t2
     ON t1.table2_id = t2.id
     WHERE t1.id IN ('1','3')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5502f/22)

Comment: @AntonGuba if you look the time when he posted his answer , i posted the answer first , i think he copy paste my answer .